# how to get the true path of a file from radupload

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radupload

I have this radupload:

```
 <telerik:RadUpload ID="RadAsyncUploadBoxLogo"  ClientID="RadAsyncUploadBoxLogo"

                                                            runat="server" ControlObjectsVisibility="None"
                                                            MaxFileInputsCount="1" MaxFileSize="4000000" OverwriteExistingFiles="True" ReadOnlyFileInputs="True"
                                                           Height="10px" TabIndex="12" OnClientFileSelected="OnClientFileSelectedHandler"
                                                            >
                                                            <Localization Remove="" Select=" Seleccionar Imagen" />
                                                        </telerik:RadUpload>
```

And i have this tag image

```
 <asp:Image ID="ImageLogo" ClientId="ImageLogo" CssClass="ImgLogo" runat="server"/>
```

with this script I try to put the image in the image tag:

```
function myOnClientFileSelect(radUpload, eventArgs) {

    var url = radUpload.getFileInputs()[0].Value;
    $('.ImgLogo').attr("src", url);

}
```

The problem is that the variable url throws me a path: fakepath/filename , I read that the radupload throws for security so that others can not access the file path , but as how to get the real path of the file to display it on the tag image

Comment: You cannot get a path from an `<input type="file">`, but you can access the file itself and use it in the same way as you can use _Blobs_, i.e. you can generate a blob uri and point an image at that

Answer (score 2):

Where `file_input` is a reference to a `<input type="file">` and `img` is a reference to an `<img>`, in the change handler you can do

```
if (file_input.files && file_input.files.length) { // some file has been set
    // generate a blob uri to the file
    var uri = URL.createObjectURL(file_input.files[0]);
    // set this as the src of your <img>
    img.src = uri;
}
```

This code uses [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) which requires *IE 10+*, to support lower versions of *IE* you may need to use a `<canvas>` instead of an `<img>` so you can load the file differently.